# Solving an equation where the unknown appears in under the exponent and as a constant

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

I encountered a problem trying to find a solution to the following equation (the problem 9.45 from the wonderful textbook on Applied Calculus by Hoffman et.al (2013, p. 719)):

$$ A(t) = \frac{3}{k} (1 - e^{-kt}) $$

According to the exercise, we know that $ A(1) = 2.3 $ implying that

$$ 2.3 = \frac{3}{k} (1 - e^{-k}) $$

Here I don't know what to do. I played with the equation back and forth trying to multiply and divide both sides of it with all sorts of things but it did not bring me much. Of course, I can multiply both sides by $ k $

$$ 2.3 k = 3 (1 - e^{-k}) $$

And it looks like $ k = 0 $, which cannot be correct as the whole equation does not make sense in terms of the context the problem is given (it is about the content of a drug in patience's bloodstream, therefore there has to be a real-number solution.)

Wolfram Alpha suggests that [the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.3%20%3D%203%20%2F%20k%20*%20(1%20-%20exp(-k))) is $ k = 0.557214 $

Could you suggest me an analytical solution to the equation?

Comment: This equation is a "transcendental equation", so there is likely no simple formula for $k$ in terms of so-called "elementary functions".  But there are plenty of ways of approximating the solution, which is what Wolfram Alpha has done.

Comment: I asked a similar question before and was given a helpful answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735552/solving-ex-6x-for-x-without-a-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "analytical" answer is $$k = \frac{30}{23} + W\left(-\frac{30}{23} e^{-30/23}\right) $$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

But I doubt that Hoffman et al intended you to solve it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: it cannot be $k=0$ not only because it does not make sense, but because you would be dividing by 0 in the first equation.