# What does x equal $\ln x - \frac{x}{10} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\ln x - \frac{x}{10} = 0$$

Graph of the equation is as follows:
[image]

what does $x$ equal to?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(x)+%3D+x+%2F+10

Comment: you can use a numerical method to solve this

Comment: You can find an approximate solution for the smallest root: take $x = 1 + \epsilon$ then if $\epsilon$ is small we have $\ln(x) \approx \epsilon$ which leads to $\epsilon = 1/9$ and $x = 10/9 = 1.11\cdots$. This turns out to be good to $0.02\%$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Approximation to the Lambert W function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463055/approximation-to-the-lambert-w-function)

Comment: We have $x=(\sqrt[10]{e})^x$. If you don't like to use the Lambert W-function you can use the recursion $x_{n+1}=(\sqrt[10]{e})^{x_n}$ with e.g. $x_0:=1$ to get the *first* solution. For the *second* solution you can use $x_{n+1}=10\cdot\ln x_n$ with e.g. $x_0:=3$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not usually any simple solution to this type of equation.  One can express the solution in terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but that is not really any help.

Numerical methods can easily produce an approximate answer to any degree of precision.  The larger root is very close to 35.77152063957296 and the smaller root is very close to 1.11832559158962974166.

(I did this with no sophisticated techniques at all; I used the “bisection method”, which goes like this: Say that $f(x) = \ln x-\frac x{10}$. We know from your graph that $f(2)> 0$ and $f(100)<0$, and the root is in between.  Check the sign of $f(50)$. This is negative, so there must be a root between $2$ and $50$.   Now check $f(25)$.  This is positive, so the root must be between $25$ and $50$.  Repeat as desired.)

Comment: how is the W function not an answer? it IS the answer. many packages evaluate the function and it can be done just by iterating Newtons method

Comment: @crow It's not an elementary function and most people don't learn about it before taking complex analysis (and perhaps not even then). It's not a (good / useful ) answer at the level this question is asked.

Comment: @crow The issue is like saying the solution to $\sin(x)=0,|x|\le\pi/2$ is $x=\arcsin(0)$. To what use is this other than to call it a name when there may exist better solutions?

Comment: The answer on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735552/323744) post has an excellent explanation on this sort of topic.

Comment: Another example is solving $x^2=2^x$ for $x$ in terms of the Lambert W function for $x>0$. Clearly it can be done, but what use is it if we know the solutions are $x=2,4$?